# preg_match for mm/ddd/yyy hh:mm

Tags: php, date, csv, time, preg-match

I'm trying to separate two values which is the date and time from a column in my csv file

this is the example of the values:

```
12/01/2012 2:31
12/02/2012 3:31
12/03/2012 9:31
12/04/2012 11:31
12/05/2012 10:31
```

I'm trying to separate them so that i can store them on different tables on our database,
but i don't know how to separate them using preg_match.

this is what i'm trying to accomplish:

```
$col5 = '12/04/2012 11:31';

preg_match( '/^({2}\/\{2}\/\{4})\ \(\d+:\d+)$/', $col5,  $matches )
$date = $matches[1];
$time = $matches[2];
```

output should be:

```
$date = '12/04/2012';
$time = '11:31';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to save on over complication why not just [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string variable:

```
<?php
$date_time = '12/01/2012 2:31';
$exploded_date_time = explode(" ",$date_time);
$date = $exploded_date_time[0];
$time = $exploded_date_time[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` function.

```
$dateTime = '16/04/2014 5:11';
$dateTimeList= explode(" ",$date_time);
$date = $dateTimeList[0];
$time = $dateTimeList[1];
```